# ¿Uso de Callback sin funcion anonima en php?

Tags: php, web, php5

ando buscando como hacer una funcion con callback que donde no se le pase como callback una funcion anonima si no una funcion ya declarada.

Entiendo que para llamar un callback lo puedo hacer de esta forma

```
private function create($callback)
    {
     //acciones
      if(is_callable($callback)){
        call_user_func($callback,$billModel);
      }
    }
```

llamado de la unfcion

```
this->create(function($model){
 echo $model;
})
```

pero en el ejemplo anterio se usa una funcion anonima lo que quiero es pasarle no una funcion anonima si no una funcion ya declarada por ejemplo

```
    private function create($callback)
    {
      //acciones
      if(is_callable($callback)){
        call_user_func($callback,$billModel);
      }
    }


    private function attachInstances($billModel)
    {
      //hace algo
    }

//llamado de la function 
$this->create($this->attachInstances)
```

intente hacer ese llamado de la funciona pero no funciona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pasa el nombre de la función como parámetro a.

```
call_user_func('my_callback_function');

call_user_func(array('MyClass', 'myCallbackMethod'));

is_callable(array('Foo', '__construct'))
```

prueba:

```
$this->create(array($this,'attachInstances'))
```